# Mouse cursor lag after lock screen, 64 bit 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, lock-screen

Recently I have noticed that when I return to my computer after it has been "locked" for a while, the mouse pointer has significant lag. The cursor position appears to only update a few times a second. Moving the mouse results in the pointer "following" the movement in a jerky kind of way, and then continuing for some fraction of a second after I have stopped using the mouse.

Replacing the mouse has no effect. (I have two differently branded and constructed usb optical mice). Plugging either mouse into a different usb port has no effect.

Once the problem was resolved by "suspending" the system, and then re-starting it with the power switch, but this does not work every time. So far, the only fool-proof fix is to shut the system down and re-start it (re-boot).

I have tried this [suggested fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129883/ubuntu-12-04-w-unity-mouse-lag). It had no effect.

Comment: This problem affects ALL USB 2.0 devices attached to my system. When performance is normal, I can copy files from a USB 2.0 card reader to my desktop at 16MB/s. When the problem manifests, I can only copy at 450kB/s.
USB scanner performance is acceptable after boot, miserable when the problem manifests.

Comment: FWIW, I've had this problem when I had a bad USB hub. Even if it's on another port, it's the same BUS. For the purposes of experimenting, what happens when *only* the mouse is plugged in, and nothing else in any USB port?

Answer (score 3):

After months of this recurring problem, I believe I have finally found the cause:

Intel Sandy Bridge GPU power management - when i915 rc6 is enabled, I get occasional USB slowdowns after resuming from a lock screen. With it disabled, the symptoms are gone for good.

Here's precisely what I did: Edited the file `/etc/default/grub` to include the line

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.i915_enable_rc6=0"
```

Comment: That totally works for me, though it only takes effect after reboot.