# Mouse Speed far too slow on new Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS install

Tags: 20.04, usb, mouse

I've just installed 20.04.2 LTS onto a new PC, but even on the highest setting the mouse speed is far too slow.

For reference I'm dual booting and had no problems with the mouse speed in Windows 10 so I don't think its  the mouse. I've also tried another couple of mice but same issue. I've also tried plugging the mouse into different USB ports.

I've tried installing xkbset, but no amount of playing with the setting on this makes any difference e.g.

```
xkbset ma 50 20 20 30 300
```

I've also tried playing with the gsettings e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse speed 1
```

But this was already set at 1 and makes no difference. I've also tried both 'adaptive' and 'default' accel-profiles, but no difference.

The only thing I can think of is its the 4k display (with 125% scaling) which is just too large for the mouse speed.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this would be very much appreciated! Many thanks in advance, Steve

Comment: You've tried a lot a things indeed. Assuming you're running standard Ubuntu (Gnome) please open system settings > mouse and touchpad. Does increasing the speed there suits your needs?

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto thanks for the reply, yes I’ve set the mouse speed in the settings to the max value, but it’s really slow. Hoping there may be some way of setting the acceleration above the standard “maximum”.

Comment: Does your mouse have a DPI button?

Comment: Hi @KGIII thanks for the reply, no it doesn’t. Would it help if it did? Am happy to investigate a new mouse if it’ll cure this!

Comment: I suspect it'd cure the problem. The DPI is basically how far the cursor moves per increment of travel. So, a low DPI means you move the mouse an inch and the cursor moves an inch. A high DPI might mean that you move the mouse an inch and the cursor moves four inches. Your mouse may just have a really low DPI on purpose, especially if it's a special-purpose mouse for refined work like artistry. You can get a cheap mouse with a DPI button to test. I recently got one on Amazon for like $15 and it works just fine.

Comment: @KGIII many thanks for this, I’ve ordered up an adjustable mouse with a max DPI of 10k, fingers xd this will fix it, will post the results.

Comment: Please do follow up. It *should* resolve your problem. You can turn the DPI way up and very little movement will send the cursor across the screen. One of the DPI settings will be your 'sweet spot'.

Comment: @KGIII new mouse finally arrived, dpi adjusted higher and its now working a treat :) Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: I tossed up a simple/quick answer. Thanks for following up. I figured that it'd work.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mouse may have a low DPI, perhaps even a 1:1 setting. Increasing the acceleration isn't going to help much.

The easiest solution is to get a mouse that has an adjustable DPI and turning it up to the point where it matches your needs/expectations. There are many available and they're not expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my USB mouse from USB 2.0 socket to USB 3.0 socket on the rear side of the motherboard and voila! it works normally now!! I was misunderstanding with other solutions like, zoom, DPI. I don't know why this works but it does.

Comment: Funny someone else recommended switching from USB 3 to 2: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu

Comment: Switching ports probably just reinstalls something which resets settings.

Answer (score 0):

For 3m ergo mouse, the switch from USB 3.0 to USB 2.0 did help but still was not enough.

In my xinput settings for the device:

```
xinput --list-props "Forward USB Optical Mouse"
```

I found:

```
Device 'Forward USB Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    ...etc
```

I changed this temporarily to test:

```
xinput --set-prop "Forward USB Optical Mouse" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190)" "3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.000000"
```

Ie, multiplying each non-zero number by 3

Then when happy, I applied this to my existing fix for my 3m ergo mouse at:

```
nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/42-middle-mouse-scrolling.conf
```

Which now contains the new final line:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Middle Mouse Button Scrolling"
    MatchProduct "PixArt USB Optical Mouse|Forward USB Optical Mouse|Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse"
    Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
    Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
    Option "ScrollButton" "2"
    Option "Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190)" "3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.000000"
EndSection
```

Note that the Match Product contains a number of variations of the 3m ergo mouse I have had over the years. Maybe it helps someone else, so leaving that in.