# Ubuntu 22.04.1 - intermittent mouse stutter/lag - Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, mouse, kde

My USB mouse will stutter/lag every 3-4 seconds intermittently, the Xorg.0.log shows some relevant events while this is happening:

[  1279.431] (EE) event3  - Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 42ms, your system is too slow

[  1279.526] (II) event3  - Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.

Its a new install, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with KDE.
Nvidia drivers are updated to 515 (GTX 980)
Intel i7-8086K
16 GB RAM

- tried disabling "flipping" and enabling "force full composition pipeline" in Nvidia settings
- removed the mouse and tried a different one
- tried a different usb port
- disabled autosuspend for all USB devices
- cpu/mem/disk io seems fine during these events

Unfortunately this stutter makes the system unusable, I'd rather not go back to windows. Anything else I can try to fix this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after fixing this issue. It was a conflict between the KDE compositor and steam apps with proton.

To identify the issue I was running a windowed Sudoku app from steam (likely any windowed steam app could be used), Konsole was open at 90% opacity (less than 100% opacity not possible when compositor enabled):

```
tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i mouse
```

Then I opened a firefox window and rapidly moved it around in a circle. Immediate messages about SYN_DROPPED events seen in konsole and lag for the mouse cursor moving the window.

I forced compositor to disable when running anything from steam

```
open "Window Rules - System Settings" -> new rule 
add property -> Window Class (application) -> Regular Expression -> steam_app.*
add property -> Block compositing -> Force -> yes
```

Hopefully this helps someone, when I was attempting to google the problem I was sent down a number of paths that did not help at all.